# VB.NET MouseEventArgs for dynamiclly added controls

Tags: vb.net, dynamic, drag-and-drop

I'm currently trying to create a tower building tool, this is based on drag and drop functionality. I'm currently ready for the user to build his tower, but now I would also like to add the option that he can adjust his tower. This by dragging the added blocks so they swap position.

I'm currently using the flowlayoutpanel to arrange my added block's (groupboxes). These are newly created after each dragevent based on the input.

[image]

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub BODY_ADD_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles _
        BODY_ADD_CILINDER.MouseMove,
        BODY_ADD_CONE_DOWN.MouseMove,
        BODY_ADD_CONE_UP.MouseMove,
        BODY_ADD_HEAD_DOWN.MouseMove,
        BODY_ADD_HEAD_UP.MouseMove

    ' Initiate dragging.
    Me.DoDragDrop(sender, DragDropEffects.Copy)

End Sub

Private Sub BODY_Arrange_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles _
BODY_LAYOUT_PANEL.MouseMove

    ' Initiate dragging.
    Me.DoDragDrop(sender, DragDropEffects.Copy)

End Sub

Private Sub FlowLayoutPanel1_DragEnter(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles BODY_LAYOUT_PANEL.DragEnter

    ' Check the format of the data being dropped.
    If (e.Data.GetDataPresent(GetType(PictureBox))) Then
        ' Display the copy cursor.
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy
    Else
        ' Display the no-drop cursor.
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub BODY_LAYOUT_PANEL_DragDrop(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles BODY_LAYOUT_PANEL.DragDrop

    Dim oPB = e.Data.GetData(GetType(PictureBox))
    Dim oGB As New GroupBox

    oGB.Name = "Test" & GET_BODY_ITEM_NO()

    oGB.Visible = True
    oGB.Width = 520
    oGB.Height = 119


    If oPB.name = BODY_ADD_CILINDER.Name Then
        oGB.Text = "Cilinder" & GET_CILINDER_ITEM_NO()
        BODY_LAYOUT_PANEL.Controls.Add(oGB)
        FILL_CILINDER_GROUP_BOX(oGB)

    ElseIf oPB.name = BODY_ADD_CONE_DOWN.Name Then
        oGB.Text = "Cone down" & GET_BODY_ITEM_NO()
        BODY_LAYOUT_PANEL.Controls.Add(oGB)

    ElseIf oPB.name = BODY_ADD_CONE_UP.Name Then
        oGB.Text = "Cone up" & GET_BODY_ITEM_NO()
        BODY_LAYOUT_PANEL.Controls.Add(oGB)

    ElseIf oPB.name = BODY_ADD_HEAD_DOWN.Name Then
        oGB.Text = "Head down" & GET_HEAD_DOWN_ITEM_NO()
        BODY_LAYOUT_PANEL.Controls.Add(oGB)

    ElseIf oPB.name = BODY_ADD_HEAD_UP.Name Then
        oGB.Text = "Head up" & GET_BODY_ITEM_NO()
        BODY_LAYOUT_PANEL.Controls.Add(oGB)

    End If

End Sub

Private Sub FILL_CILINDER_GROUP_BOX(ByVal oGB As GroupBox)

    Dim oPB As New PictureBox
    oPB.Dock = DockStyle.Left
    oPB.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
    oPB.Image = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("Cilinder")
    oPB.Name = oGB.Name & "_PictureBox"
    oGB.Controls.Add(oPB)

    Dim oLBL1 As New Label

    oLBL1.Name = oGB.Name & "_LABEL_HOOGTE"
    oLBL1.Text = "Hoogte"
    oLBL1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(128, 25)
    oLBL1.Width = 42
    oGB.Controls.Add(oLBL1)

    Dim oLBL2 As New Label

    oLBL2.Name = oGB.Name & "_LABEL_DIKTE"
    oLBL2.Text = "Dikte"
    oLBL2.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(138, 52)
    oLBL2.Width = 32
    oGB.Controls.Add(oLBL2)

    Dim oLBL3 As New Label

    oLBL3.Name = oGB.Name & "_LABEL_ORIENTATIE"
    oLBL3.Text = "Orientatie LW"
    oLBL3.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(311, 25)
    oLBL3.Width = 72
    oGB.Controls.Add(oLBL3)

    Dim oLBL4 As New Label

    oLBL4.Name = oGB.Name & "_LABEL_SEGMENTEN"
    oLBL4.Text = "Segmenten"
    oLBL4.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(322, 52)
    oLBL4.Width = 61
    oGB.Controls.Add(oLBL4)

    Dim oTB1 As New TextBox

    oTB1.Name = oGB.Name & "_TB_HOOGTE"
    oTB1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(176, 22)
    oGB.Controls.Add(oTB1)

    Dim oTB2 As New TextBox

    oTB2.Name = oGB.Name & "_TB_DIKTE"
    oTB2.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(176, 49)
    oGB.Controls.Add(oTB2)

    Dim oTB3 As New TextBox

    oTB3.Name = oGB.Name & "_TB_ORIENTATIE"
    oTB3.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(389, 22)
    oGB.Controls.Add(oTB3)

    Dim oTB4 As New TextBox

    oTB4.Name = oGB.Name & "_TB_SEGMENTEN"
    oTB4.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(389, 45)
    oGB.Controls.Add(oTB4)

End Sub

Private Function GET_BODY_ITEM_NO()
    Return (BODY_LAYOUT_PANEL.Controls.Count)
End Function

Private Function GET_CILINDER_ITEM_NO()

    Dim s As String
    Dim y As Integer = 1

    For i = 0 To BODY_LAYOUT_PANEL.Controls.Count - 1
        s = BODY_LAYOUT_PANEL.Controls.Item(i).Text

        If s.Contains("Cilinder") Then
            y = y + 1
        End If
    Next

    Return (y)
End Function

Private Function GET_HEAD_DOWN_ITEM_NO()

    Dim s As String
    Dim y As Integer = 1

    For i = 0 To BODY_LAYOUT_PANEL.Controls.Count - 1
        s = BODY_LAYOUT_PANEL.Controls.Item(i).Text

        If s.Contains("Head down") Then
            y = y + 1
        End If
    Next

    Return (y)
End Function
End Class
```

For the rearranging part I would have to create a drag-event for the dynamically added groupboxes. How do you write this? How should I specify what to handle?

**So the Question is**: How do I hook the mouse-event to the dynamically added group-box control?

```
Private Sub BODY_REARRANGE_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles
```

Also if there are any comments on my sample code I could use some pointers!

Comment: Are you asking about hooking up mouse *events* or something about `MouseEventArgs`?  Not at all clear

Comment: Sorry about that, the question is how to hook the mouse event to a control that is dynamically added? Normally I would do: handles groupbox1.mousemove

Comment: use AddHandler for dynamically created controls